# UsbBulkInPipe doesn't return the actual values

Tags: c#, usb, windows-8.1

I am using `UsbBulkInPipe` to obtain data from my USB device. When I read data the length is correct but value are all zeros. How I can read the real data?

This is what I've tried:

```
UInt32 bytesRead = 0;
UsbBulkInPipe bulkIn = device.DefaultInterface.BulkInPipes[0];

var stream = bulkIn.InputStream;
DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream);

try
{
    bytesRead = await reader.LoadAsync(bulkIn.EndpointDescriptor.MaxPacketSize);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    //ShowStatus(exception.Message.ToString());
}
finally
{
    byte[] value = new byte[bytesRead];
    reader.ReadBytes(value);
}
```

Comment: eurgh, I remember having this problem. Time to dig through my WinUSB code

Comment: Your code looks like it is designed to just ignore all errors.  Is any exception getting thrown?  What is the finally block supposed to do?  Also, you don't show the part of the code that actually prints the byte values, and there could be a bug in that part.  How about making an SSCCE?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I am using this method:

```
var t = reader.LoadAsync(buf.MaxPacketSize).AsTask(cancellationTokenSourceBulkIn.Token);    
uint len = t.Result;

byte[] data = reader.ReadBuffer(len).ToArray();
```